# Arduino Mega 2560 getting error while using the Arduino UNO as ISP and mega as programmer

Tags: microcontroller, arduino

I have recently purchased a new Arduino Mega 2560. I intend to upload code using the ICSP (In-Circuit Serial Programming) method same as directly through the MOSI and MISO pins, which is the standard approach. I initially followed the instructions on the website https://www.instructables.com/ATMEGA2560-Standalone-Using-Arduino-UNO/
and successfully uploaded the code. However, after some time, I attempted to upload a new sketch using the same method (Tools -> Upload using Programmer), but encountered an error. Is there a way to erase the chip and upload a new bootloader to the Arduino Mega 2560?

avrdude: Device signature = 0x0000ff
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega2560 is 1E 98 01
Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

When attempting to upload code directly through AVRmkll, I'm encountering the following error messages: "avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout" and "avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer."

Comment: the instructions are for standalone ATmega2560. why do you program an Arduino Mega over ISP? why do you used an Uno for that if you have an AVRmkll?

Comment: In anticipation of future needs, I aimed to upload the code using the ICSP (In-Circuit Serial Programming) method. The objective was to avoid the necessity of purchasing an entire ATmega 2560 board, allowing me to utilize the ATmega IC 2560 instead. However, during this attempt, I encountered an error that is hampering my progress.

Comment: you write "Arduino Mega 2560" but you mean "Atmel ATmega2560"? one is a dev board and the other is an MCU https://store.arduino.cc/collections/boards/products/arduino-mega-2560-rev3 https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atmega2560

Comment: and what is with the Uno and the AVRmkll?

Comment: I'm stuck uploading a program to the Atmega2560 board. It shows an error. Could you please visit the website I mentioned? After reading the comments, you'll see others facing the same issue. However, there's no solution yet. I thought it'd be better to upload new firmware via DFU mode, but the Atmega2560's LED stays on in DFU mode without uploading anything. What's the solution to install new firmware on the Atmega2560? I request you to visit the website i mentioned. thnks

Comment: what DFU mode? ATmega2560 doesn't have DFU

Comment: do you have the AVRmkll programmer? dd you wire it correctly?

Comment: About the link I mentioned, did you see it? If yes, is using Arduino Mega 2560 as target and Arduino UNO as ISP correct as per given ? If it is, I followed their instructions, but encountered an upload error. Device signature was 0x0000ff, yet avrdude displayed 0x1e9801. After research, I concluded that by changing 0x1e9801 to 0x0000ff in the expected file, I triggered chip erase and write. However, it led to a subsequent error. I found a new device signature, so I'm retrying the process. It keep changing the Device signature

Comment: In response to your question, yes, I wired everything correctly. I attempted the DFU mode approach as well, but I learned from you that it doesn't support DFU. Thank you.

Comment: AVRmkll is a blue box with a cable. I guess you don't have it. so you use Uno with the "Arduino as ISP" sketch and you selected "Arduino ISP" in the Programmers menu. do you have a capacitor on Uno's reset pin to suppress the auto-reset of Uno?